# Amazon Lex Bot - Replying to Hello

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have started learning Amazon lex, gone through their Documentation and Example Bots.

Problem i am facing is that all the bots are Q&A types, if i have to make the bot reply to Hello, what should be the correct way or how to do it?

According to my understanding :

> I am thinking of creating an intent for Hello and when it gets
>   fulfilled i can make the bot reply **How can i help you?** with Lambda Function, this is the
>   way it is supposed to be done?

There can be many other direct question that user can ask, do i have to reply all the question for an intent with lambda function? I am using java script.

I am stuck, suggest any method ?

**EDIT 1** : [How to give response based on user response in Amazon Lex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706177/how-to-give-response-based-on-user-response-in-amazon-lex)

This is what i was looking for, still any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: What language are you planning to use in a Lambda Function?

Comment: @JayA.Little i am planning to use java script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement returning a formatted response from **JavaScript (Node.js)** in a Lambda Function:

First create some handy functions for building proper Lex response formats.

```
function close(sessionAttributes, fulfillmentState, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Close',
            fulfillmentState,
            message,
        },
    };
}
```

You can find more Node response-building functions like that in [AWS-Lex-Convo-Bot-Example index.js](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-convo-bot-example/blob/master/index.js)

Then just call that function and pass it what it needs, like this:

```
var message = {
    'contentType': 'PlainText', 
    'content': 'Hi! How can I help you?'
}

var responseMsg = close( sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', message );
```

(write your message inside 'content', if using SSML tags, change 'contentType' to 'SSML')

Then pass `responseMsg` to the `callback` of `exports.handler`.

---

Put it all together and you get:

```
function close(sessionAttributes, fulfillmentState, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Close',
            fulfillmentState,
            message,
        },
    };
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log( "EVENT= "+JSON.stringify(event) );

    const intentName = event.currentIntent.name;
    var sessionAttributes = event.sessionAttributes;

    var responseMsg = "";

    if (intentName == "HelloIntent") { // change 'HelloIntent' to your intent's name
        var message = {
            'contentType': 'PlainText', 
            'content': 'Hi! How can I help you?'
        }

        responseMsg = close( sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', message );
    }
    // else if (intentName == "Intent2") { 
    //      build another response for this intent
    // }
    else {
        console.log( "ERROR unhandled intent named= "+intentName );
        responseMsg = close( sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', {"contentType":"PlainText", "content":"Sorry, I can't help with that yet."});
    }

    console.log( "RESPONSE= "+JSON.stringify(responseMsg) );
    callback(null, responseMsg);
}
```

Comment: callback(responseMsg) gives error but callback(null,responseMsg) works fine. i figured it out by looking at the example given, can you tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the answer. Yes the `callback` function of `exports.handler` takes 2 attributes, the first is an `error` message, the second is the `response` message. So `callback( null, responseMsg )` tells it there is no error so deliver the response.